# Ticking sound from rear wheel/brake after longer unuse

Tags: toyota, noise, brake-rotor, yaris

I have a Toyota Yaris 1.3 from 2000. I was not using the car for *10 days* and today when I wanted to drive it I noticed a *ticking sound* from the rear end. The sound is there always, even for very low speeds, it starts almost immediately after the vehicle starts to roll. When the speed is higher, the ticking is more frequent. The ticking is not subtle, it's louder. The ticking was not present before at all.

It's summer, there is no salt on the road.

I want to check out the brake rotors, maybe some crack or something?

What would the preferred way to diagnose this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This could be where the pad got stuck to the disc over time.

You should check the discs - you may see a pad shaped mark where it was stuck. A light clean with very fine glasspaper will probably be sufficient.

It may be that it is on the reverse side so you will need to jack up and support the car properly and get the wheel off to see.

Comment: Now I am not entirely sure, about the brake rotor. The car may have drum brakes. Would your answer apply to that case as well?

Comment: same idea - shoes can stick but I have found it is less likely as there is usually a lar4ger gap but it can still happen, check clean and test...

Comment: It could be from the emergency brake pad as well.